# Ruby - What's the strftime equivalent of hhh:mm:ss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strftime

I know that hh:mm:ss is `time_object.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`. I'm using this formatting for a length of time that's over 24 hours so the hour portion overflows. What's the correct way to get hhh:mm:ss in strftime?

EDIT: Example requested.

What happens:

```
Time.at(90000).utc.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
=> "01:00:00"

Time.at(432000).utc.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
=> "00:00:00"
```

What I want to happen:

```
Time.at(90000).utc.something_else
=> "25:00:00"

Time.at(432000).utc.something_else
=> "120:00:00"
```

Comment: what is the input and expected output?

Comment: Please show your `time_object`

Comment: I updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby does not natively have a duration class, time objects only specify points in time. Thus, `Time#strftime` will always have hours in `0-23` range. Durations are expressed as numbers, with `1` being one second; and needless to say, `Float` does not have `strftime` method.

If you need durations, you will need to make them yourself, or use a library that already does it for you (for example, [duration](https://github.com/peleteiro/ruby-duration)).

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Amadan's explanation, here's an easy way to compute time offsets for the time string format you wish to use:

```
require 'time'

def new_time(basetime, offset)
  sign = (offset[0]=='-') ? - 1 : 1
  str = (sign==1) ? offset : offset[1..-1] 
  hrs, mins, secs = str.split(':').map(&:to_i)
  basetime + sign*(60*(60*hrs + mins) + secs)
end  

basetime = Time.parse('Apr 1, 2015') #=> 2015-04-01 00:00:00 -0700
new_time(basetime,   "8:22:34")      #=> 2015-04-01 08:22:34 -0700 
new_time(basetime,  "38:22:34")      #=> 2015-04-02 14:22:34 -0700 
new_time(basetime, "138:22:34")      #=> 2015-04-06 18:22:34 -0700 
new_time(basetime,  "-8:22:34")      #=> 2015-03-31 15:37:26 -0700
```